# Included Plugin in Nuxt bad rendering performance

Tags: vue.js, animation, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am adding a snippet from this codepen https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/Ffvlo to display a particle animation. I'm adding it like this in my nuxt.config.js file:

```
plugins: [
    { src:'~/plugins/particles.js', mode:'client'}
  ],
```

It shows up and works but unfortunately the performance is so bad that the animation is not really perceivable as it should be. Is there anything I could do differently so that the performance is the same as on the codepen?

Also i am aware that this is now registered as a global plugin and always loaded. Is there a way to add it only to a specific site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by performance can you create an example on codesandbox? Its a canvas element, unless you changed to something like `( ( ROWS = 500 ) * ( COLS = 500 ) )` it would be the same performance, maybe dont data-bind to any of the vars which might be controlling the particles.

Comment: yeah its global, if you don't want global, import on the page/component

Comment: Particles.js has an unsolved bug with destroy/recreation and it’s abandoned, you should try Particles.vue (not vue-particles it uses the same buggy library) or tsParticles instead, it’s a fixed version of that library https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles